# second page values not changing after navigate from first page

Tags: flutter

I made a simple formula calculator app, which have two pages, first page have three text fields where i put values and after that i want to show the answer list so i made the second page where i will show answer list. my issue is that in first attempt it shows the answer but in second attemt it shows the still previous calculation answer which means second page states not changing so how could i fix this. here is my code.

This is my first page code where i put values in text fields.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:angles/angles.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:milling_machine_calculator/layout/answerCode.dart';
import 'package:milling_machine_calculator/layout/const_sizes.dart';
import 'package:milling_machine_calculator/layout/repeateCode.dart';
import 'itemList.dart';
import 'package:milling_machine_calculator/views/pages/global.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:milling_machine_calculator/layout/answerCode.dart';

class Milling extends StatefulWidget  {

@override
State<Milling> createState() => _MillingState();
}

class _MillingState extends State<Milling> {
TextEditingController diaFIeldController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController teethFIeldController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController degreeFIeldController = TextEditingController();


String depth='';
String modcutter='';
String dpCutter='';
String dpCutterNumber = '';
String teethNumber = '';
String mdCutterNumber = '';


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

void gearCalculation(){
   var diaField = diaFIeldController.text;
   var teethField = teethFIeldController.text;
   var  degreeField = degreeFIeldController.text;

   if(diaField.isEmpty || teethField.isEmpty || degreeField.isEmpty ){
     Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Please enter value in fields field',backgroundColor: 
Colors.grey,textColor: Colors.black);
   }
   else{
     double diaField2 = double.parse(diaField);
     double teethField2 = double.parse(teethField);
     double degreeField2 = double.parse(degreeField);
     print('dia $diaField2');
     print('teeth $teethField2');
     print('degree $degreeField2');

     double finalDia = diaField2 / 25.4;
     double cos1 = Angle.degrees(degreeField2).cos;
     double finalCutter = ((teethField2 + 2) / finalDia) / cos1;
     dpCutter = finalCutter.toStringAsFixed(3);
     double moduleCutter = 25.4 / finalCutter;
     modcutter = moduleCutter.toStringAsFixed(3);
     double finalCutterDepth = 0.08534 * moduleCutter;
     depth = finalCutterDepth.toStringAsFixed(3);
     double tan1 = Angle.degrees(degreeField2).tan;
     double pitchDia = -((2 / finalCutter)-finalDia);
     finalPitchDia2 = pitchDia;
     double pitchDia2 = ((pitchDia * pi) / tan1) / 10;
     finalPitchDia = pitchDia2;
     print('pitch dia $finalPitchDia');

     if(teethField2 < 14){
       dpCutterNumber = '8';
       teethNumber = '12-13 T';
       mdCutterNumber = '1';
     }
     else if (
     teethField2 <16
     ){
       dpCutterNumber = '7';
       teethNumber = '14-16 T';
       mdCutterNumber = '2';
     }
     else if (
     teethField2 <20
     ){
       dpCutterNumber = '6';
       teethNumber = '17-20 T';
       mdCutterNumber = '3';
     }
     else if (
     teethField2 <24
     ){
       dpCutterNumber = '5';
       teethNumber = '21-25 T';
       mdCutterNumber = '4';
     }
     else if (
     teethField2 <35
     ){
       dpCutterNumber = '4';
       teethNumber = '26-34 T';
       mdCutterNumber = '5';
     }
     else if (
     teethField2 <56
     ){
       dpCutterNumber = '3';
       teethNumber = '35-55 T';
       mdCutterNumber = '6';
     }
     else{
       dpCutterNumber = '0';
       teethNumber = '0 T';
       mdCutterNumber = '0';
     }
   }

}
void leadCalculation(int index) {
 setState(() {
   print('final dia$finalPitchDia');
     for(double i =2; i<101; i++){
     double driver = i;
     firstListItem.add(driver.toString());
     double loopField = finalPitchDia * driver;
     print(driver);
     print(loopField);
     double driven = loopField.roundToDouble();
     secondListItem.add (loopField.toStringAsFixed(3));
     double cal1 = (driven / driver) * 10;
     double cal2 = (finalPitchDia2 * pi) / cal1;
     String cal2parse = cal2.toStringAsFixed(3);
     double cal2parse2 = double.parse(cal2parse);
     double invT = (Angle.atan(cal2parse2).degrees);
     thirdListItem.add(invT.toStringAsFixed(3));
   }
     Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=>itemList()));
 });
}

final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title:
    Text(
      'Lead gears calculator',
        style: appBarText,
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  ),
  body: Container(
    height: double.infinity,
    width: double.infinity,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0,top: 5.0),
            child: Text(
              'Note:\n    Please put Dia of HELICAL GEAR,teeth and degree.',
              style: noteText,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child:
          Container(
            height: size.height / 5,
            width: size.width / 1.05,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                  spreadRadius: 5,
                  blurRadius: 7,
                  offset: Offset(0,3),
                ),
              ]
            ),
            child:
                ListView(children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                  Center(
                    child:
                    Text('Required Fields',
                      style: puText,),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      repeateTextFieldCode(
                          controller: diaFIeldController,
                          lableText: 'DIA'),
                      repeateTextFieldCode(
                          controller: teethFIeldController,
                          lableText: 'TEETH'),
                      repeateTextFieldCode(
                          controller: degreeFIeldController,
                          lableText: 'DEGREE')
                    ],
                  )
                ],),
          ),
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child:
            Container(
              height: size.height / 2.0,
              width: size.width / 1.05,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                      spreadRadius: 5,
                      blurRadius: 7,
                      offset: Offset(0,3),
                    ),
                  ]
              ),
              child:
              ListView(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                  Center(
                    child: Text('Answer Box',
                      style: puText,),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                  repeateAnswerCode(cutterText: 'Dp C: ', cutterField: '$dpCutter /',
                  numField: 'Num: $dpCutterNumber/ ',
                  teethField: teethNumber,),
                  repeateAnswerCode(cutterText: 'Md C: ',
                  cutterField: '$modcutter/',
                  numField: 'Num: $mdCutterNumber/ ',
                  teethField: teethNumber,),
                  Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child:
                    Container(
                      height : size.height / 10,
                      width: size.width / 1.1,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                            spreadRadius: 5,
                            blurRadius: 7,
                            offset: Offset(0,3),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text('Cutter Depth: ',
                            style: puText,),
                          Text(
                              depth
                            ,
                            style: fieldsText,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              ],),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              InkWell(child:
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: size.height / 15,
                  width: size.width /2.2,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  child:  Center(
                    child: Text('Answer',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'Alfa',
                          fontSize: 20.0
                      ),),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
                onTap: (){
                  setState(() {
                    gearCalculation();
                  });
                },
              ),
              InkWell(child:
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: size.height / 15,
                  width: size.width /2.2,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  child:  Center(
                    child: Text('Lead Gears',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'Alfa',
                          fontSize: 20.0
                      ),),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
                onTap: (){
                    leadCalculation(0);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
 );
}
```

}
This is my second page code where i show answer list.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:milling_machine_calculator/layout/const_sizes.dart';
import 'package:milling_machine_calculator/views/pages/global.dart';

class itemList extends StatefulWidget {
const itemList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<itemList> createState() => _itemListState();
}
Future<Set<List<String>>> addCalculation() async{
return {firstListItem, secondListItem, thirdListItem};
}
class _itemListState extends State<itemList> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
      'Lead gears list',
      style: appBarText,
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  ),
  body:

  ListView.builder(itemBuilder:(BuildContext context, int index){
    print('index= $index');
    return
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
          height: size.height / 8,
          width: size.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 7,
                offset: Offset(0,3),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child:
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: size.height / 27,
                    width: size.width / 6,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('Driver',style: fieldsText2,),),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 75.0,),
                  Container(
                      height: size.height / 27,
                      width: size.width / 6,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                      child: Center(child: Text('Driven',style: fieldsText2,))),
                  SizedBox(width: 75.0,),
                  Container(
                    height: size.height / 27,
                    width: size.width / 6,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    child:Center(child: Text('Degree',style: fieldsText2,)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0,),

              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(firstListItem[index],style: fieldsText,),
                  SizedBox(width: 50.0,),
                  Text(secondListItem[index],style: fieldsText,),
                  SizedBox(width: 50.0,),
                  Text(thirdListItem[index],style: fieldsText,),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
  },
    itemCount: firstListItem.length,
  ),
);
}
}
```

And this is my global variables code where i store answer list values .

```
double finalPitchDia = 0;
double finalPitchDia2 = 0;
List <double> driver = [];
List <double> driven = [];
List <String> firstListItem = [];
List <String> secondListItem = [];
List <String> thirdListItem = [];
```

Comment: Easiest way is to use a provider instead of global variables

Comment: but in variables the values are changing on every calculation but in clientView the values are not changing so this is not the variables issue i think so.

Comment: so just to clarify, the first page that shows the answers is working well, but the second page (itemList which is also the clientView) is not updating?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like every time you go to the `Lead Gears` page (itemList), you execute the `leadCalculation` function that has

```
firstListItem.add()
secondListItem.add()
thirdListItem.add()
```

so for every other attempt, it would add the results to the same list in addition to the previous results. The list will then include answers from both previous attempt AND new attempts. You would have to scroll down past the first 101 results to find the start of the next results.

To fix this you need to clear the list first to delete the old results.

```
void leadCalculation(int index) {
      setState(() {
        print('final dia$finalPitchDia');
        firstListItem.clear();
        secondListItem.clear();
        thirdListItem.clear();
        for (double i = 2; i < 101; i++) {
          ...
        }
```